# How can I use Identity with my existing database ASP.NET Core MVC and EF Core (DB-First)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, ef-database-first

I am using ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC and EF Core 5 for my project. I created a SQL Server database with a table `User`, but when I started to implement authorization, registration and role management, I decided to use Core Identity.

I have looked through many articles, learned how to reverse engineer models from the original database (`Scaffold-DbContext`), how to create a database based on Identity `AspNetRoles`, `AspNetUsers` and etc with own properties using inheritance (`Add-Migration`)...

But I didn't find the answer to the main question: how can I use Identity with my existing database, for example, specify in the table ("Basket") the foreign key to `AspNetUsers([Id])`, while maintaining all the functionality of Core Identity. Maybe I should use 2 DbContexts or something else, I don't know, I am just a beginner.

My `IdentityContext` with custom Roles & Users:

```
public partial class HotelServiceContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{
    public HotelServiceContext()
    {
    }

    public HotelServiceContext(DbContextOptions<HotelServiceContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<int>>().ToTable("UserTokens");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>().ToTable("RoleClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Roles");

    }
}
```

My `DBContext`, which I got from executing the command `Scaffold-DbContext` (it also contains work with the Identity tables, which I previously created in the database using `Update-Database`).

```
public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}

public virtual DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<AppUser> AppUsers { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Basket> Baskets { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Feedback> Feedbacks { get; set; }

// ... And other generated code.
```

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Ok, at now I have found a workaround for this problem. I added the generated code from my existing database to `IdentityContext`, after that in the `OnModelCreating` method I added a dependency to the `AspNetUser` table with `API Fluent` and delete generated `DBContext`. It seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Before .NET Core there used to be a very easy GUI too to accomplish this. Basically, you need to create a DbContect by reversing engineering the SqlServer Identity Database.
In .NET 5(Core) you are required to use the Scaffold-DbContext on the project's PackageManager Console. However, it is not intuitive. **It fails when attempting to create the "Model" as part of the main Project.**
The answer it to create a new project with a single empty class. Then, run the Scaffold-DbContext on that project. The entire reversed engineered SqlServer Identity Db is built completely in that classes' Model. A one time event! Very clean. Build it, then reference it from the main project. Actually, much faster and cleaner than the old way.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=win2k22.ladybug.xxxx;initial catalog=xxxxx ;user id=Remotexxx;password=Remotexxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force
```